# A Water Jug Problem

Tags: calculation-puzzle, decanting-problems

Suppose you are given two jugs: a 4-gallon one and 3-gallon one, and neither has any markings on it.
You have a pump that can be used to fill the jugs with water.
What do you do so that exactly 2 gallons of water are left in the 4 gallon jug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Fill the 3 gallon jug, drop to the 4 gallon. Refill the 3 gallon and use it to top the 4 gallon jug. You'll have 2 gallons on the 3 gallon jug. Empty the 4 gallon and move the water in the 3 gallon to the 4 gallon.

Answer (score 3):

Fill J4             J4=4 J3=0
Fill J3 using J4    J4=1 J3=3
empty J3            J4=1 J3=0
pour J4 in J3       J4=0 J3=1 
Fill J4             J4=4 J3=1
Fill J3 using J4    J4=2 J3=3

Answer (score 2):

1. Fill 3 gallons of water into 3 Gallon jug. (3G Jug=3G water, 4G Jug=0G Water).
2. Pour it into 4 gallon Jug. (3G Jug=0G water, 4G Jug=3G Water).
3. Fill Again 3 gallon of water into 3G jug. (3G Jug=3G water, 4G Jug=3G Water).
4. Now put this 3 gallon water of 3 gallon jug into the 4 gallon jug until it fill completely. As 4 gallon jug has only a gallon water space in it. so 3 gallon jug now contains exactly 2 gallons of water.
5. Drop out 4 gallons water in 4 gallons jug.
6. Pour 2 gallons water into 4 gallon jug from 3 gallon jug.